# how to display image if knows image data as binary?

Tags: c#, image

If I can retrieve image data from sql-server database, which stored as image type. How can I display the image in my web application using c#? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an http handler that returns the image

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Byte[] yourImage = //get your image byte array
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(yourImage);
            context.Request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (yourImage).LongLength.ToString());
            con.Close();

            context.Response.End();
            context.Response.Close();
        }
```

You can can do that by creating a GenericHandler file type from the visual studio and add the previous code in then you can call you can write the url of the generic handler as the image source

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a good solution, I mean creating a GenericHandler file.

Comment: @SamirAdel I think BinaryWrite should come after adding the headers to get the proper file type.

Answer (score 2):

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayFromDB);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this as well

```
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[]) imageReader.GetValue(0);    
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes); 
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(imagePath);
fs.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Position());
```