# Converting binary data to image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was stuck with how to retrieve an image from MySQL database and convert it from Binary format to Bitmap Image to display it in `ASP:Image` or `HTML Image`. I am able to upload image but its being converted to Binary data and I couldn't understand how to convert it back to Bitmap format :(

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT picture from profile limit 1", MyConnection);
    MyConnection.Open();
    OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows == false)
    {
        Response.Write("No rows");
    }
    if(dr.Read())
    {
        // WHAT TO CODE HERE?
    }
}
```

Anybody please help me in fill the code with **WHAT TO CODE HERE** part.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878161/how-to-display-image-if-knows-image-data-as-binary

Comment: you need to convert the image to a byte[] array..

Comment: "Binary" is an encoding, not a format. There are many different binary encodings; which one does your database use? JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, et al. are formats. What format do you want to output?

Comment: Your web application need not convert the binary byte stream to an image. The browser does that. All you need to do is return the stream with the correct content-type and the browser will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify this method, it should do the trick:

```
        public BitmapImage ConvertToImage(System.Data.Linq.Binary binary)
    {
        byte[] buffer = binary.ToArray();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: or if he doesn't understand that he can look at this link for how to stream Images from a Database .. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx

Comment: I am getting an error with `BitmapImage` are you missing the reference?

Comment: Whops, don't think you can use BitmapImage's in asp.net. As far as i know, it's a part of PresentationCore.dll... Try the part that says "The rest is piece of cake" http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Retrieving-Images-from-a-Database--C---Part-II/

Answer (score 0):

Add "PresentationCore " dll from add reference to get System.Windows.Media.Imaging dll referred inorder to get rid of the missing ref error... :)